# OneJar running other classes

Tags: java, jar

Is it possible to run the main method on other classes when using onejar? It works fine as an executable but I want to be able to run other classes without having to repackage.

e.g.

```
java -jar myonejar.jar  //works fine



java -cp .;myonejar.jar test.Test //Error: Could not find or load main class
```

Comment: This should work.  Are you sure you're specifying the right class?

Comment: What is the main class from the manifest of your jar?

Comment: Yup its the right class...I thought maybe it has something to do with the structure of onejar jar?

Comment: The main class from the manifest is test.Test